# Induced inverse limit sequence

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, functors, spectral-sequences

[This](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/lim%5E1+and+Milnor+sequences#PropertiesOfLim1) proposition states that given the functor $\underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}^1 \colon Ab^{(\mathbb{N}, \geq)} \longrightarrow Ab$ and the short exact sequence $0 \to A_\bullet \to B_\bullet \to C_\bullet \to 0 \;\;\; \in Ab^{(\mathbb{N}, \geq)}$, the following long exact sequence is induced:
$$0 \to \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_n A_n \to \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_n B_n \to \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_n C_n \to \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_n^1 A_n \to \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_n^1 B_n \to \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_n^1 C_n \to 0.$$

The proof of this proposition creates a short exact sequence of chain complexes. The long exact sequence is then the long exact sequence of cohomology groups where the $k^{th}$ cohomology groups are trivial for $k \geq 2$.

I now want to consider the long exact sequence induced by the functor $\underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}^1 \colon Ab^{(\mathbb{N}, \geq)} \longrightarrow Ab$ and the exact sequence $0 \to A_\bullet \to B_\bullet \to C_\bullet \to D_\bullet \to 0 \;\;\; \in Ab^{(\mathbb{N}, \geq)}$.

I think that in this case, we will NOT have an induced sequence of the form:
$$0 \to \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_n A_n \to \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_n B_n \to \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_n C_n \to \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_n D_n \to \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_n^1 A_n \to \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_n^1 B_n \to \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_n^1 C_n \to \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_n^1 D_n \to 0.$$

Is that correct? If so, **What kind of sequence will be induced instead?** (That's my question.) Will there be an induced spectral sequence? I admit that I am not yet familiar with spectral sequences, but the reason I suspect there will be one in the 4-term exact sequence case is because I read that while a long exact sequence of cohomology arises from a short exact sequence, a spectral sequence arises from a 4-term exact sequence.

Comment: @SergeyGuminov I think my question relates more to the snake lemma hidden in the background which falls apart when we have a 4-term exact sequence instead of a 3-term short exact sequence. But if this is incorrect, I would be very happy to know!

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Could you briefly clarify what you see as the answer to my question? Is it that yes, that 8-term sequence holds?

Comment: Four-term exact sequences are not very common starting places. I suggest that you look at some examples to see if you can identify any relationships among the various terms involved — $\lim$ and $\lim^1$ of the various sequences. Have you done this? If so, please report your findings as part of the question.